# Import header files in IDA to get the struct definitions?

Tags: ida, windows, idapython, c, idapro-sdk

I am reversing a program that has a lot of internal structs in it.

The problem is that there are a lot of structs, so i can't import them manually using local types->insert.

Lets say i have some header files that have all the definitions of these structs (but obviously a lot of other stuff as well like defines, since its an actual header file), is there anyway i can import this in IDA?

I cannot manually add structs because there are more than 1000 structs in these header files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a header using [File > Load file > C header file](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1367.shtml) or [create a type library](https://github.com/trou/apache-module-ida-til) beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CLIthen do something like: `ida_typeinf.idc_parse_types("filename.h", idc.PT_FILE)`. See [this](https://github.com/tmr232/idapython/blob/master/python/idc.py) file for more options. Also check this [link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/61405468935/) for GUI, they also explained how to setup your header file. Hope this helps.